# Hiding/Removing Cygwin/X 'Start' Menu icon from showing on Windows Desktop

Tags: cygwin, cygwin-x

I'm running Cygwin/X (with qt3) under windows 7, and in a modal style, fixed in the top left of my desktop, I have this annoying X icon, which presents me with a cygwin/X/Start menu, style list of application.  I want to at the very least, make it not modal (so I can put other windows on top of it), but ideally get rid of it all together.

In my setup I have 3 screens, arranged with my 2 large screens side by side, above my smaller, primary screen (on my laptop).  I usually work, with Chrome in my large, left screen, and my development environment in my large right screen.  Hence the icon in question, blocks me from seeing the first tab, in Chrome.

It 'feels' like an X application, and the fact that it's not responding to the usual Windows Manager stuff, makes me think it's part of the cygwin windows manager (which I think is xwin), but why it's occupying the top left of my desktop, and how I move it, is beyond me.

Does anyone else, know what this is or, how I move/close it?

Answer (score 1):

sibaz,

I was annoyed by this icon as well.  I would also like to get rid of it, but do see the utility in having the menu readily available.  So, to get rid of the eyesore, I did the following, which works well for my needs.

the file in question resides in:
"/home/username/.config/fbpanel/multiwindow"

I changed the line:

```
Autohide = false
```

to:

```
Autohide = true
```

Then, (re)start the Cygwin X Server.

The icon will be in the upper-left-hand corner, given the default configuration with this one change, but should hide its relatively unattractive face when not needed.

I did not mess with the other settings present in this config file.  Perhaps there is more to play with there to get exactly what you are looking for.

Best of luck!
Matthew Wells Sanders